# Swift Animate Background not working from a collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, jquery-animate

I have this code to change the background of a collection view cell, but for some reason, it's not working.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    })
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Does the change work without the animation? If not, the animation has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The change does work without the animation. With or without animation, it works the same. It changes the background instantly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property `backgroundColor` is not animatable for the cell, I think. What you really want is to blend from one color to another.

One solution is to set the color of the `backgroundView` and animate its `alpha`. You could also insert your own views as backgrounds and animate their alphas in opposite directions to create the change.

Yet another solution is to drop down to the `layer` level and animate the layer background color.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {() -> Void in
    self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
})
```